# Use of parentheses changes how pointer-dereference and increment behaves

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int* n){
    *n++;
}

int main() {
    int n= 1;
    f(&n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

The value of `n` doesn't change.
If I want to change the value of `n` I must do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int* n){
    (*n)++;
}

int main() {
    int n= 1;
    f(&n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Why are the parentheses so important, and what's the difference between these two lines of code?

```
*n++;
(*n)++;
```

Comment: `2+2*2 != (2+2)*2`

Comment: Because operators have precedence over others. And the compiler needs to know whether `*n++` is `(*n)++` or `*(n++)` - since they do very different things

Comment: Your question is confusing because you have two variables named `n`, so it's unclear which you mean when you say "the value of n doesn't change". In the first version, `n` in the `f()` function changes. In the second version, `n` in the `main()` function changes.

Comment: Order of precedence. *n++ bumps the pointer. (*n)++ bumps the value at the pointer, as does ++*n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. The precedence of postfix operator `++` is higher than the pointer dereference operator `*`. And so the compiler will interpret `*n++` as `*(n++)`. To change the order in which operators are applied, you must use parentheses.

To be clear about the differences:

- `*n++` increments the *pointer*, returns the original pointer and dereferences it which results in no change to the integer it points to. It is essentially a "no-op", and any half-decent compiler would optimize your entire function away because it does nothing.
- `(*n)++` dereferences the pointer and increments the integer it was pointing to, which is exactly what you wanted.

You can find a full table here: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

As always, it usually doesn't hurt to add parentheses tactfully, even if it captures the same ordering as the language specifies. This is a courtesy to anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
void f(int* n){
    *n++;
}
```

is the same as

```
void f(int* n){
    n++; // increment of local (stack) variable.
    *n; // reads undefined memory which is foolish but harmless in this instance
}
```

and is obviously quite pointless (if you'll pardon the pun.)

Comment: Well, they are not quite the [same](https://godbolt.org/z/P4Pb81Yvv).

Comment: @Bob__ Problem is, your example USES the value pointed at... Your `g( )` in not the same as above. My answer only "reads" that value as a superfluous no-op statement like the statement `42;` Apples and oranges, Bob...

Comment: Yes, it uses the value. Note that the OP says "The value of n doesn't change. If *I want to change the value* of n I must do this". So, removing a cause of undefined behavior, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/h3d6son6P) seems a good example to me. If your point is that none of those behaves as OP expects, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

[operator precedence table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syEGw.png)

(TR)sağdan sola = (EN)from right to left

(TR)soldan sağa = (EN)from left to right

credit: Necati Ergin

For the answer to your question, you should learn the operator priority table. parentheses are at the top of the priority table.

The increment operator and the indirection operator are at the same priority level. But the priority direction is from right to left for this level.